# Simulate Bootstrap's Focus CSS

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple inputs in a form and I would like to be able to apply Bootstrap's blue highlight to text fields that are not currently in focus using JQuery.

Comment: have you tried anything??

Comment: [Please show what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/). If you don't, your question is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap's :focus style is:

```
textarea:focus, input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, input[type="datetime"]:focus, input[type="datetime-local"]:focus, input[type="date"]:focus, input[type="month"]:focus, input[type="time"]:focus, input[type="week"]:focus, input[type="number"]:focus, input[type="email"]:focus, input[type="url"]:focus, input[type="search"]:focus, input[type="tel"]:focus, input[type="color"]:focus, .uneditable-input:focus {
border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
outline: 0;
outline: thin dotted \9;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}
```

You can copy the style into a css class:

```
.focus {
    border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
    outline: 0;
    outline: thin dotted \9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}
```

then just add `focus` to your input field's className

ugly but works

Answer (score 1):

With bootstrap less, apply the `.tab-focus()` mixin to add focus styling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you want to apply jquery's input glow to unfocused text field then you can simply use css:

```
input:not(:focus){
    border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,0.6);`
    outline: 0 none;
}
```

You can add more selector like :not([type=button]):not([type=submit]) ect.